# How to check if string has certain characters without using regex

Tags: python, string

I am trying to verify the my string only contains the following values, '\n, '.', and 'o'. They do not all need to be there, but if anything outside of those characters is included my function should return false.

I have one string that does include these characters, but it also includes '0'. With my function though, this returns to true.

```
I am primarily having issues with the first line, all others work as expected. I am not able to use regex so an alternative would be greatly appreciated!
```

Comment: This may not refere to the question, but this is a bad practice to use structures like if (len(s)==10 or len(s)== 14) and s[2]=='\\': return True. Your statement under if ((len(s)==10 or len(s)== 14) and s[2]=='\\') returns bool itself. It will be more correct to write like return (len(s)==10 or len(s)== 14) and s[2]=='\\'

Answer (score 3):

Use the `all` function:

```
if all (char in ".o\n" for char in s):
```

If you prefer, make a list of chars instead of a string:

```
if all (char in ['.', 'o', '\n'] for char in s):
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use sets for this:

```
if s and set(s) - set('\n.o'):
  return False
# s consists entirely of \n, o and .
```

It's not clear to me what should happen if `s` is empty.  The above code would allow it; if you wish to reject it, change the first line to

```
if set(s) - set('\n.o'):
```

Comment: You could remove the conditional and just do `not set(s) - set('\n.o')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you could do it:

```
allowed_chars = ['\n', '.', 'o']
your_string = '\n.o'

all([False for i in set(your_string) if i not in allowed_chars])
```

Returns `True`.

And `your_string = '\n.ogg'` returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
tests = [
  r'ab\cdefgho',
  r'ab\cdefgh.',
  r'ab\cdegh\n',
  r'ab\cdc.o\n'
]

def check_string(s):
  if ('\\n' in s) or ('.' in s) or ('o' in s):
    if (len(s)==10 or len(s)== 14) and s[2]=='\\':
      return True
    else:
      return False
  else:
    return False

for t in tests:
  assert check_string(t)
```